# How do I disable touchpad tap-to-click on an Acer Aspire v3 572?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, acer-aspire

Running Windows 7. I want to turn off the tap-to-click feature without disabling the whole touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

I was having difficulty with this on Windows 7. I wanted to turn off the tap-to-click feature of the touchpad without having to disable the whole thing (which I can do with Fn + F7). The drivers that are installed by default under Win 7 do not have any touch-pad specific settings, only general mouse settings. Also the drivers that are available on the support page for the Acer v3-572 are not correct. When/if you install them, Windows will tell you that no changes were made because the existing (default) drivers were already up-to-date. You can manually install the drivers, but even so, it will not enable the "Device Settings" tab from the mouse control panel.

Instead download the Synaptic drivers from http://www.synaptics.com/resources. Pick the correct OS (Win 7 for me) and then run the setup program. This will install the drivers but may not actually set your touchpad to use that driver. If not, you will need to manually update the driver after it has been installed. To do this

1. Open device manager [win_key + pause/break (key above pageup)]  --> Device Manager
2. Mice and other pointing devices
3. Select (dbl-click) on PS/2 compatible mouse
4. Driver tab
5. Update Driver
6. Browse my Computer
7. Let me pick from a list
8. Uncheck "Show compatible hardware"
9. From manufacturer select "Synaptics"
10. Select Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad
11. Click next
12. Ignore dire warning about unsigned driver.
13. Install
14. Restart

You now have two days to disable/customize the touch-pad. First, you should have a system tray icon that likes like a white page thing. Right click on it and choose ClickPad Properties (or play around with the other options from the menu). You can also get to the same ClickPad Properties by going to Start --> Control Panel --> Mouse --> Device Settings Tab --> Settings.

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: good answer. for mine, i have a dell, the touchpad drivers were created by them. they had a support page that had them for download.